# sql server partitioned table

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, partitioning

I am preparing for 70-451 exam. There is a question I got:

You are a database developer. You plan to design a database solution by using SQL Server 2008. The database will contain a table named Claims. The Claims table will contain a large amount of data. You plan to partition the data into following categories:

- Open claims
- Claims closed before January 1, 2005
- Claims closed between January 1, 2005 and December 31, 2007
- Claims closed from January 1, 2008 till date

The close_date field in the Claims table is a date data type and is populated only if the claim has been closed. You need to design a partition function to segregate records into the defined categories. 
what should you do?

- A Create a RANGE RIGHT partition function by using the values 20051231, 20071231, and 20080101.
- B Create a RANGE RIGHT partition function by using the values 20051231, 20071231, and NULL.
- C Create a RANGE LEFT partition function by using the values 20051231, 20071231, and 20080101.
- D Create a RANGE LEFT partition function by using the values 20051231, 20071231, and NULL.

Can someone answer this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've looked at this a few times, and I can't see any of them being right.

The partition for claimes before Jan 1 2005 partition is not generated by any of them, since the first partition value on any answer is 20051231. Whether LEFT / RIGHT is used is then immaterial, every value up until 31st Dec 2005 is in a single partition, and the LEFT / RIGHT is just about whether that date is included.

I would of expected a left with 20041231, or a right with 20050101 to be in the mix somewhere.

If the answers all started with 20041231 instead of 20051231, then I would take answer D as correct. Either question has a typo, or the test does.

Comment: Yeah, that really confused me a lot. I'd agree with you. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exam this week and this question came up.  I commented this question with the non related date 20051231.